# 'self' is not a valid target. Mixing Objective-C and C++ (Objective-C++)

Tags: c++, objective-c, selector, objective-c++

I have come some way with mixing C++ and Objective-C (actually Objective-C++), but now I am stuck.

My current problem is that the Objective-C 'self' variable seems to not be correct and throws an exception in my code:

```
Exception: Invalid parameter not satisfying: target
```

Which I assume refers to that selfRef is not a valid target:

```
addTarget:selfRef
```

What is the correct way to initialize 'self' and make it available for a C++ function.

This is my first day ever touching objective-c/objective-c++ so excuse me if this might be elementary ;)

**Code:**

```js
#import "ios_objc.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPRemoteCommandCenter.h>

id selfRef;
//static Ios_objc *selfRef; //I tried this as well.

@implementation Ios_objc

IosImpl::IosImpl(void) //: self( NULL )
{

}

IosImpl::~IosImpl(void)
{
    [Ios_objc dealloc];
}

void IosImpl::init(void)
{
    selfRef = [[Ios_objc alloc] init];
}

void IosImpl::enable(void)
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = YES;

    @try {
        [commandCenter.playCommand addTarget:selfRef action:@selector(playSounds)];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception.reason);
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}

void IosImpl::playSounds()
{
        NSLog(@"Play");
}

//I also tried 'Objective-C' style function signature.
//- (void) playSounds
//{
//
//}

@end
```

Comment: @SeekAddo: Ops, removed!

Comment: Try to use it as Nullable and init selfRef in the class constructor

Comment: From your code here, `selfRef` is a global variable. That means it does not belong to one instance of `IosImpl`; there is just one variable that is shared among all the instances of `IosImpl`. The way you memory-manage `selfRef` inside `IosImpl` makes it seem like you think the `IosImpl` instance owns `selfRef`, which is not true.

Comment: For example, if you have two `IosImpl` instances alive at the same time, the second one created would have overwritten the `selfRef` variable, leaking the `Ios_objc` object that the first `IosImpl` instance assigned to `selfRef` which was retained and not released; and when both `IosImpl` instances destruct and both send `release` (if you correct your code according to the accepted answer) to the object pointed to by `selfRef`, it would over-release the second `Ios_objc` object that was only retained once.

Comment: I have already come a bit further on this bridging topic and have among other handled what you mention. Maybe I can post the final code when I'm done for further Googlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the exception is coming from a statement within the implementation of `-[MPRemoteCommand addTarget:action:]` that looks something like:

```
NSParameterAssert(target);
```

That is, it's validating that the `target` parameter it has received is non-`nil`. That's why the odd phrasing "… parameter not satisfying: target". "target" is the actual condition being tested and which the parameter does not satisfy. If the statement had been written `NSParameterAssert(target != nil);` then the exception reason would have read "… parameter not satisfying: target != nil", which would have been clearer.

Anyway, you write a (presumably non-`nil`) value to `selfRef` in `IosImpl::init()`, but what calls that? The constructor does not as currently written. Either call `init()` from the constructor or just put that code directly into the constructor.

Also, your destructor isn't correct. As currently written, it's calling `-dealloc` on the `Ios_objc` class object, which is unlikely to do anything (and, if it does, it's nothing good). You probably meant `[selfRef release]` (**note:** `release`, not `dealloc`). In general, you should never call `-dealloc` except to call through to `super` in an implementation of your own `-dealloc` method.

Comment: I noticed that nothing was calling init() so I am now calling it in the constructor, but still get the same error, which I think is strange.

Comment: Have you tried putting a logging statement in `init()` to both prove it's being called and to show the value of `selfRef`? Also, have you checked/logged the value of `selfRef` in `IosImpl::enable()` where it's used?

Comment: You were correct. The init() was not called. Not here nor in the C++ wrapper class I have. Also I changed the destructor to what you suggested, as what I had caused a crash.